# python nested list unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, list, nested

I've ran into an unexpected behavior when using a nested list in python, that took a while to debug. If a list is initialized like this:

```
a = [[None] * 2] * 2
a
[[None, None], [None, None]]
```

and another list initialized like this:

```
b = [[None, None], [None, None]]
b
[[None, None], [None, None]]
```

I would expect the same behavior from both these lists, but if I do:

```
a[0][0] = 3
a
[[3, None], [3, None]]
```

and if I do:

```
b[0][0] = 3
b
[[3, None], [None, None]]
```

Can someone explain the reason why this happens? thanks

Comment: its not as good as a debugger but sometimes putting your code into something like http://www.pythontutor.com/ can help you understand whats going on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = [[None] * 2] * 2
>>> id(a[0])
41554168
>>> id(a[1])
41554168
>>> b = [[None, None], [None, None]]
>>> id(b[0])
41549576
>>> id(b[1])
41557368
```

This should explain

Comment: I agree ... but I suspect it is not sufficient for OP .. (+1 all the same)

Comment: http://goo.gl/zJtrzY should help him understand also I think

Comment: Is there any way to make list a to work like list b? For example, if I have list of 1000+ items, it would be better to multiply