# Python nested array indexing - unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory-management, indexing

Suppose we have an input array with some (but not all) nan values from which we want to write into a nan-initialized output array. After writing non-nan data into the output array there are still nan values and I don't understand **at all** why:

```
# minimal example just for testing purposes

import numpy as np

# fix state of seed
np.random.seed(1000)
# create input array and nan-filled output array
a = np.random.rand(6,3,5)
b = np.zeros((6,3,5)) * np.nan

x = [np.arange(6),1,2]
# select data in one dimension with others fixed
y_temp = a[x]
# set arbitrary index to nan
y_temp[1] = np.nan
ind_valid = ~np.isnan(y_temp)
# select non-nan values
y = y_temp[ind_valid]

# write input to output at corresponding indices
b[x][ind_valid] = y
print b[x][ind_valid]
# surprise, surprise :(
# [ nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan]

# workaround (that will of course cost computation time, even if not much)
c = np.zeros(len(y_temp)) * np.nan
c[ind_valid] = y
b[x] = c
print b[x][ind_valid]
# and this is what we want to have
# [ 0.39719446         nan  0.39820488  0.68190824  0.86534558  0.69910395]
```

I thought the array `b` would reserve some block in memory and by indexing with `x` it "knows" those indices. Then it should also know them when selecting only some of them with `ind_valid` and be able to write into exactly those bit addresses in memory. No idea, but maybe it's sth. similar as [python nested list unexpected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421624/python-nested-list-unexpected-behaviour)? Please explain and maybe also provide a nice solution instead of the proposed workaround! Thanks!

Comment: `x = [np.arange(6),1,2]` will create a fancy index, thus, a *copy* is made, not a slice-view. Note, Python list slices *always* copy, and `numpy.ndarray` slices create views instead.

Comment: Ok, I'm using this fancy index, because in general I want to select one dimension from the N-D array while looping through other dimensions like

    `for coord in itertools.product(*index_grids):
        z_old = list(x_old + list(coord))`

x_old would be for example the np.arange(6) and coord would be (1,2)

Comment: The issue is that the number of dimensions can principally be arbitrary. Any suggestions for the assignment of the data into the output?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand you, but unless you use slices, you cannot create views, and copies will have to be made.

Comment: But according to what you wrote b[x] should already be a copy not a view into b. So why does the second example work?

Comment: Because you do `b[x] = c`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165035/discussion-between-bproxauf-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).